# Maximizing a sum minus its maximal summand

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, inequalities, permutations, combinatorial-optimization

This is a followup to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751863/maximise-left-sum-i-1n-p-i-cdot-i-right-left-max-j-1n-p-j/4757264#4757264) that appeared on m.SE:

> Maximize $\displaystyle f(\pi)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\pi_i}\right)-\max_{1\le i\le n}{(i\pi_i)}$ over permutations $\pi\in S_n$.

The problem originally appeared in a [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/contest/1859/problem/C) competition, but the emphasis there seemed to be on checking all permutations of a given size efficiently rather than on a theoretical solution. I suggested to the OP on m.SE to repost the question here, but nothing happened in 2.5 months, so I am doing the reposting.

First, some necessary notation. Let $\oplus$ and $\ominus$ denote the direct sum and skew-sum of permutations, respectively. For example, $12387654=123\oplus54321=123\oplus(21\ominus 1\ominus 21)$.

Now, let $\pi_n^\ast$ be any maximizing permutation of size $n$. (Note that $\pi_n^\ast$ need not be unique, and indeed is not unique for some $n$. For example, when $n=7$, we can choose $\pi_n^\ast=1237654$ or $\pi_n^\ast=1234765$.) Checking a few small cases suggests that $\pi_n^\ast$ is of the form $I_{n-m}\oplus J_m$, where $I$ is the identity permutation, $J$ is the reversal of the identity, or equivalently, the identity $I_n$ with the right suffix of length $m$ reversed. Moreover, one of the answers [shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4757038/499816) that assuming $\pi_n^\ast$ is of this form implies that we can choose and $m=\left\lfloor \sqrt{2n+1} \right\rfloor$.

I attempted a partial [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4757264/499816) to try to prove that $\pi_n^\ast$ should indeed be of the above form. Briefly, my idea was to show that $\pi_n^\ast=L\oplus(H\ominus 1\ominus M)$, where the "$1$" corresponds to the entry maximizing the product $i\pi(i)$, then to show that the block $L$ is increasing (easy), and blocks $H$ and $M$ are decreasing. However, this approach seems to get bogged down in details that make me wonder if there is a more efficient method to solve this problem (or this kind of problem) that somehow avoids the long slog to what seems to be a nice and simple answer. So, that is my question: is there a better way to solve this (kind of) problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I note that $\sum i\pi_i$ is sometimes called the [cosine of a permutation](https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000342/), and by a [result](https://doi.org/10.37236/1993) of Joshua Sack and Henning Úlfarsson [*Electronic Journal of Combinatorics* **19** (2012), #P29 (27 pages)], the problem is equivalent to *minimizing* $\textsf{invsum}(\pi)+\max(i\pi_i)$, where $$\textsf{invsum}(\pi)=\sum_{\substack{1\le i<j\le n\\\pi_i>\pi_j}}(j-i)$$
is the [inversion sum statistic](https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000055/).

Comment: You might want to fix (an upper bound to) $\max i\pi_i$ and then maximize $\sum i\pi_i$ as a function of that, and then maximize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. The proof rests on several observations.

The first one is that if you want to maximize $\sum_i i\pi_i$ under the condition $\pi_j\le B_i$ with any prescribed $B_i$, then your best bet is to follow the greedy algorithm first choosing the highest available value for $\pi_n$, then the highest available of the remaining values for $\pi_{n-1}$ and so on. Indeed, if at any moment you fail to greedily choose the highest available value in your admissible configuration, you can look at the first time you did it, find the place where it went, and then do the swap. The resulting configuration will still be admissible and will produce a higher sum.

Now, following the Command Master's suggestion (I wonder if he or she actually had a full solution already but decided just to make a hint) suppose that we have some $K$ and want to maximize the sum $\sum_i i\pi_i$ with the restrictions $B_i=\frac Ki$ and then look at the difference of the resulting maximum and $K$. Let $k=\pi_n$ in the optimal permutation. Then notice that we must have $K<n(k+1)$ (or we weren't greedy at the first step). Since for $\ell< n-k$ we have
$$
(n-\ell)(k+\ell+1)=nk+n+\ell(n-k-\ell-1)\ge n(k+1)\,
$$
we cannot choose the value greater than $k+\ell$ for $i=n-\ell$. Obviously, we cannot take more than $n$ for $i=k$ either. If we make that choice, then the remaining values can and should be assigned in the decreasing order in our greedy algorithm resulting in the permutation $1,2,\dots,k-1,n,n-1,\dots k$ as desired. This permutation will work for $K=nk+\lfloor(n-k)^2/4\rfloor$ and above, so it remains to figure out what will happen if we drop $K$ from there to something that is still at least $nk$.

Suppose that in our greedy algorithm $\ell\in [1,n-k]$ is the least number when we cannot choose $\pi_{n-\ell}=k+\ell$. Then, clearly, $\ell\le\frac{n-k}2$ (beyond that point we start going *down* in our products). Note that $\pi_{n-(\ell-1)}=k+(\ell-1)$ was still admissible, so our gain from diminishing $K$ compared to the conjectured "standard" permutation is at most
$$
G=\frac{(n-k)^2}4-(n-k)(l-1)+(l-1)^2.
$$

Now let's estimate the loss. First of all, the highest available value for $i=n-\ell$ is now $k-1$ ($k+\ell$ and above are impossible and the values from $k$ to $k+\ell-1$ have been taken already). So $\pi_{n-\ell}=k-1$. From there up to $i=k+\ell$ the value in the standard permutation should drop by at least $1$ because the products there are above $(n-\ell)(k+\ell)$. Even if this were the only restriction on them (the actual one is stronger and if we relax the restrictions, we get the larger maximal possible sum), our greedy algorithm would produce $\pi_{n-j}=k+j-1$ from $n-j=n-\ell-1$ up to $n-j=k+\ell$, so the values $k+\ell,\dots, n-\ell+1$ have all traveled one position to the right. As to $n-\ell$, it is now forced from position $k+\ell$ all the way to $k-1$ because at $k+\ell-1,\dots,k$ we already have higher than $n-\ell$ admissible values, so swapping any of them for $n-\ell$ would contradict our greedy assignment. Thus, the total loss is at least
$$
L=(k+\ell)+(k+\ell+1)+\dots+(n-\ell-1)+(n-\ell)(\ell+1)-(k-1)(n-\ell-k+1)
\\
=\frac{(n-k-2\ell)(n+k-1)}{2}+(n-\ell)(\ell+1)-(k-1)(n-\ell-k+1)
$$
(value times shift down in position compared to the standard permutation).

It remains to check that $L\ge G$ for all positive integer values of $n>k,\ell\le\frac{n-k}{2}$ (the case $n=k$ means that we actually took $1,\dots,n$, which is of the desired kind already). Note that $L-G$ is quadratic in $\ell$ starting with $-2\ell^2$, so it is enough to check the endpoints $\ell=1$ and $\ell=\frac{n-k}2$ (ignoring the integer requirement on $\ell$ in the latter case).

If $\ell=1$, we get
$$
L-G=n-k-1+(n-k)[\tfrac{n-k}4+\tfrac 12]\,.
$$
If $\ell=\frac{n-k}2$, we end up with
$$
L-G=(\tfrac{n-k}2+1)^2-1\,.
$$
Check my algebra! It is notoriously bad, especially after midnight, but I hope that the argument will survive a small error in the computations (if not, let me know :-) ).